# How to convert string into json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have below code but my json result not able to parse.I don't know why it is not parsing.Please help me, class properties are same as json convert into c#

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                        {
                            client.Headers.Add("API-Version: 5.0");
                            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json");

                             ss= client.UploadString(baseAddress + "/api/Jobs/MakePayment", json);
                        }

                    try
                    {
                      //  rtn = rtn.Replace("\", " ").Trim();

                        ResponseJudo objCls = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseJudo>(ss);

                    }
```

My response json is this :

```
{\"receiptId\":\"5443635\",\"yourPaymentReference\":\"Test1964\",\"type\":\"Payment\",\"createdAt\":\"2016-09-30T07:46:50.9991+01:00\",\"result\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"AuthCode: 830476\",\"judoId\":100109768,\"merchantName\":\"\Khan\",\"appearsOnStatementAs\":\"APL/khn\",\"originalAmount\":\"11.10\",\"netAmount\":\"11.10\",\"amount\":\"11.10\",\"currency\":\"GBP\",\"cardDetails\":{\"cardLastfour\":\"3436\",\"endDate\":\"1220\",\"cardToken\":\""\",\"cardType\":1},\"consumer\":{\"consumerToken\":\"uToaxZzXSJngo0iL\",\"yourConsumerReference\":\"TestPayment2111\"},\"risks\":{\"postCodeCheck\":\"UNKNOWN\"}}"
```

Comment: what is the error and what is the class layout of ResponseJudo

Comment: pls send ResponseJudo class ?

Answer (score 1):

Running the JSON response through https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ shows multiple errors which is a result of badly formed JSON.

For instance if we replace `\"` with `"` to get the string into it's original format, cardToken looks like this

`"cardToken":""","cardType":1}`

Therefore, the actual issue is in the string variable `ss`. That needs to be fixed to return correct JSON... Also in the value `"\Khan"`, the backslash is interpreted as an escape character.